# IPhone App Approval With Wireless Communication To External Hardware

Tags: iphone, tcp, externalinterface, appstore-approval

I am working on an application that communicates via TCP/IP with an external device that controls a large piece of machinery.  How would I submit this to apple?

Do you think apple must test the hardware and machinery as well?

Can I create a demo login that acts as though it is controlling a device without any wireless communication?

Comment: Hopefully, you've taken appropriate safety precautions so someone (skynet?) can't hijack the wifi link, and use this large machine to attack Tokyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, someone else created a demo login to control some sort of online simulation of the expensive hardware, and got their app approved.

Comment: That helps a lot.  That's what I'll try:)